# Como ordenar los archivos por numero en servidor

Tags: c#, .net

En mi servidor tengo una carpeta con varios archivos que listo en un gridview, quisiera que se vieran del 1 al 10 ordenados.

Este es el código que utilizo para checar los archivos de la carpeta

```
public DataTable VerArchivos(DirectoryInfo directorio) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("NombreArchivo");
        foreach (FileInfo file in directorio.GetFiles())
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["NombreArchivo"] = file.Name;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "NombreArchivo ASC";
        return dt;
    }
```

Los archivos se muestran así:
[image: et]

Comment: y estan ordenados.. lo que pasa es que estan ordenados por numero, que en realidad es un string.. entonces el 10 esta antes que el 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que todos los archivos vayan a tener el nombre con el mismo patrón, puedes insertarlos ordenados así:

```
public DataTable VerArchivos(DirectoryInfo directorio) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("NombreArchivo");
        foreach (FileInfo file in directorio.GetFiles()
                                            .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                            .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Regex.Match(f., @"^(\d+)").Groups[1].Value)))
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["NombreArchivo"] = file.Name;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, me sale error en path-> Path.GetFileName(path) y en 
f. ->Regex.Match(f., @"^(\d+)"

Comment: Posiblemente te falten los `using` de `System.Text.RegularExpressions` y `System.IO`